# Error by running script with python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have tried to run a script with pandas in python3, but it appears to have an terrible error I even don't understand. Note: my script is "gh.py" and has an error in line 1, i can't import pandas.

`File "gh.py", line 1
    from pandas as pd
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: First of all, it's a great idea to paste your code, not just the error you get. Second of all, you use the invalid syntax, which Python interpreter points out. It should be `import pandas as pd`. Or `from pandas import *`. Not what you wrote up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: sorry, that's true, but I still have an issue, i got this problem:

'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gh.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas'

I've already installed pandas in my console with command: 'pip3 install pandas'

Comment: You probably installed it in a different environment or installed it tied to a different python install. My advice would be to install it via conda, especially if you're on windows.

Comment: Also @wim's answer is the correct answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re using python2 instead of python3. Use the appropiate syntax to import pandas and also try

> pip install pandas